# *ngIf Hide and show the div slowly and move a div slowly to right/left in angular2+

Tags: angular5

```
<div id="abc">
    <div id="bac"  ngIf="show">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
<div id="cde">cds</div>
</div>
```

I have a div want to add or remove from DOM slowly(show and hide) using *ngIf and likewise adding or removing of div.id ="bac" should cause div.id='cde' to move left or right slowly like it is animating.

Answer (score 0):

`*ngIf` probably is not he best thing you are looking for, instead of this, use `ngClass` and define the css transitions and positions for these animations.

`*ngIf` fully hides/shows a node from/in DOM, it's like `display: none/block` which is not able to be animated through css-transitions

here is an example

```
<div class="animated" [ngClass]=" { 'show': show, 'hide': !show }">
  content
</div>
```

then in the css

```
.animated {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: gray;
  transition: 1.5s linear margin-left;
}

.animated.show {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.animated.hide {
  margin-left: -120vw; 
}
```

Height also can be changed, depends on which effect you expect.

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdjemd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with working code

Comment: Nice Solution, but I am using *ngIf and can't move to show and hide of  div.id="bac" as I want to remove it from DOM. Any other solution or hack that fulfills scenario needed.